# Create a program on QTCreater version 5.9.4 MSVC217 64bit is crashed when run program

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Help me! I'm using Qt VS Tools with the Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition running on windows 10. I tried to create a new project with MSVC217 64bit compiler, but the program crashes when it is run. The Code generated is default, no changes made

> build-untitled1-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\debug\untitled1.exe...
>   Cannot retrieve debugging output.
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   The process was ended forcefully.
>   build-untitled1-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/debug/untitled1.exe crashed

Code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
      ui->setupUi(this);
    }

  MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
    delete ui;
  }
```

Comment: Provide the code snippet where it is crashing

Comment: @Gurushant "I try to create new program" ->the program is default of platform QTquick applycation-Empty

Comment: Have you set up the qt build environment for visual studio? It is located in Qt VS Tools > Qt options

Comment: @Gurushant yes, I installed and setup

Comment: Try it in release mode and see if same issue exists

Comment: I building program by release mode. debug mode same

Comment: Try running the visual studio in admin mode

Comment: After running the visual studio in admin mode, the next step?

Comment: Run the app and see if the issue exists

Comment: Edit your post and provide the code your running

Comment: I create a project and do not fix code

Comment: So you are saying the project is completely blank? Not even the default code?

Comment: I said this auto code of platform when new project is created

Comment: Qt VS Tools? QtCreator? which IDE are you using?

Comment: I resolved. Cause: I missed install "QT Creator xxx  CDB debug support". Thanks all so much!